# PHP Notice: Undefined offset error

Tags: php

This is my codes in compresser.php:

```
<?php

$filename = "isnotconverted_*";
$files = glob($filename);
$filefound = $files[0];

$new_filefound = str_replace( "isnotconverted_", '', $filefound );

$command = 'ffmpeg -i '.$filefound.' -b 64k -vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:0 [out]" '.$new_filefound;
exec( $command );

unlink( $filefound );
```

When I open `compresser.php` directly there is no error and everything is OK, but when I use `putty` and type `/usr/local/bin/php /home/dltvbourse/public_html/compresser.php`, I get this error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/dltvbourse/domains/dl.tvbourse.ir/public_html/compresser.php on line 5
ffmpeg version 0.7.11, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar  1 2015 14:55:21 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvpx
  libavutil    50. 43. 0 / 50. 43. 0
  libavcodec   52.123. 0 / 52.123. 0
  libavformat  52.111. 0 / 52.111. 0
  libavdevice  52.  5. 0 / 52.  5. 0
  libavfilter   1. 80. 0 /  1. 80. 0
  libswscale    0. 14. 1 /  0. 14. 1
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
-b: No such file or directory
PHP Warning:  unlink(): No such file or directory in /home/dltvbourse/domains/dl.tvbourse.ir/public_html/compresser.php on line 12
```

What should I do?

Comment: @LeaTano: the reason the index is undefined because no files are found. So this case is more specific.

Comment: I think,this is a variation(a flavor) of the same, but you might be right @CommuSoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the `php` file in the correct folder. So do a:

```
cd /home/dltvbourse/public_html/
/usr/local/bin/php compresser.php
```

(in `putty` or whatever ssh client you are using).

The reason this fails is because [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) uses the current directory as offset directory. Since no files of the pattern are probably placed in the initial directory it won't work.

Furthermore it is perhaps safe to rewrite your program a bit. After all it is always possible that something goes wrong and no such file is placed in the directory. In that case you probably better check the size of the array and throw an error message.

Answer (score 0):

This would remove your PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 error

> $filefound = (!empty($files[0])) ? $files[0] : false;